# Does Windows DFS always keep some files backlogged?

Tags: windows, windows-server-2003, bandwidth, dfs

I have been monitoring our DFS backlog and I have noticed that is hasn't really dropped below 1000 or so files. I am assuming this means it needs to use more bandwidth. So starting last night I allowed it to use 512Kbps between 6pm and 4am, when it used to only get 128Kbps. I noticed a large drop, but it never went below about 1500 files. I just want to be sure my conclusion about needing to use more bandwidth is correct before I tell my boss about it. I have included a graph of the data showing my stats from yesterday afternoon and last night.

[DFS Backlog Graph](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/7183919/DFS.pdf)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just for testing purposes have you tried disabling the bandwidth throttling altogether?

http://blogs.technet.com/b/filecab/archive/2006/06/14/434190.aspx

Also double check your staging settings.  More info here on proper staging calculation

http://blogs.technet.com/b/filecab/archive/2006/03/20/422544.aspx

Comment: The staging areas are all fine, I had to deal with those a week or so ago because we were hitting the limit. Thank you for the links.

I unfortunately can't disable the throttling during business hours since we have Voip traffic going over the same pipe and it would result it copious amounts of complaints. On the upside they wouldn't be able to call us.

Comment: Could you adjust it outside of business hours and notify the users that due to testing they may experience some issues?

Comment: I have slightly increased the bandwidth during business hours to see if that helps and outside of main hours I have removed the limit. So tonight I will see how it does.

Answer (score 0):

DFS doesn't keep backlogged files on its own; if this is your case, then it means something is preventing it from replicating properly. You can of course check the Event Viewer for DFS-related errors, but I agree with you that bandwidth could very well be the issue here.